# Partial Data Set in WEBI 4.0

Tags: business-objects

When I run a query in Web Intelligence, I only get a part of the data.
But I want to get all the data.
The resulting data set I am retrieving from database is quite large (10 million rows). However, I do not want to have 10 million rows in my reports, but to summarize it, so that the report has the most 50 rows.
Why am I getting only a partial data set as a result of WEBI query?
(I also noticed that in the bottom right corner there is an exclamation mark, that indicates I am working with partial data set, and when I click on refresh I still get the partial data set.)

BTW, I know I can see the SQL query when I built it using query editor, but can i see the corresponding query when I make a certain report? If yes, how?

UPDATE: I have tried the option by editing the 'Limit size of result set to:' in the Query Options in Business Layer by setting the value to 9 999 999 and the again by unchecking this option. However, I am still getting the partial result.

UPDATE: I have checked the number of rows in the resulting set - it is 9,6 million. Now it's even more confusing why I'm not getting all the rows (the max number of rows was set to 9 999 999)

```
SELECT  
I_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Segment_Value_A.Description_TXT,
count(I_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY)
FROM
I_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Segment_Value_A RIGHT OUTER JOIN
I_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A ON
(I_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Segment_Value_A.Segment_Value_KEY=I_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Segment_Value_KEY)
GROUP BY 1
```

[image: Report Screenshot]

Comment: While this may be a little off-topic, I personally would advise against loading that much data into a Web Intelligence document, especially if you're going to aggregate it to 50 rows in your report. These are not the kind of data volumes WebI was designed to handle (regardless whether it will or not). Ideally, you should push down as much of the aggregation as possible to your database  (which is much better equipped to handle such volumes) and return only the data you really need.

Comment: what is the recommended maximum number of rows to load in the date and the recommended size of data in MB?
The second question is: actually want to take one column which has about 50 distinct values, and count the occurrences  of the second column. How can I do that before I load the data in the WEBI?

Comment: See my answer (was a bit too much for a simple comment)

Answer (score 2):

The "Limit size of result set" setting is a little misleading.  You can choose an amount *lower* than the associated setting in the universe, but not higher.  That is, if the universe is set to a limit of 5,000, you can set your report to a limit lower than 5,000, but you can't increase it.

Does your query include any measures?  If not, and your query is set to retrieve duplicate rows, you will get an un-aggregated result.

If you're comfortable reading SQL, take a look at the report's generated SQL, and that might give you a clue as to what's going on.  It's **possible** that there is a measure in the query that does not have an aggregate function (as it should).

Comment: unaggregated number of rows is 9,6 million. So apart from  "Limit size of result set" property, what else can I change? At the moment, my query does not have any measures, and my query is not returning duplicate rows.

Comment: please explain what you wrote about the "Limit size of result set" setting. Did not understand that part...

Comment: You mentioned that you should only get 50 rows; so either you have too many detail dimensions in your query, or you are getting unaggregated rows.

Comment: What, specifically, are you unclear on regarding the Limit setting?  I thought my explanation was pretty clear.

Comment: I think the problem was that I did not define the correct measures. Now I have made it. Additionally, when I click on 'regenerate' to get data preview,I get the expected result. However, when I click on 'Run Query', I get the expected values in the dimension, but the measure contains only value '1'. (I have described this as a comment to Kristof's answer.) Do you know why is this happening, and how can I remedy it?

Comment: It probably has to do with the nature of the data.  It may help if you include the generated SQL in your question.

Comment: Hi Joe, just added the query. As I mentioned - I get the expected result when I click on 'Regenerate'. But when I click on 'Run the Query', and when I drag the objects, I get only value '1' in the measure.

Comment: The "1" in every row is correct; you're seeing the count of .VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY values within each VWD_Segment_Value_A.Description_TXT.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand it... It's confusing for me because when I take the same query, and run it in Database Query Tool, I get the expected result. But when I click on 'Run Query' in the WEBI, i get '1' values. Why is the same query returning sotosay different results in different tools...?

Answer (score 1):

While this may be a little off-topic, I personally would advise against loading that much data into a Web Intelligence document, especially if you're going to aggregate it to 50 rows in your report.

These are not the kind of data volumes WebI was designed to handle (regardless whether it will or not). Ideally, you should push down as much of the aggregation as possible to your database (which is much better equipped to handle such volumes) and return only the data you really need.

Have a look at [this link](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58999), which contains some best practices. For example, slide 13 specifies that:

> 50.000 rows per document is a reasonable number

What you need to do is to add a measure to your query and make sure that this measure uses an aggregate database function (e.g. `SUM()`). This will cause WebI to create a SQL statement with `GROUP BY`.

Another alternative is to disable the option *Retrieve duplicate rows*. You can set this option by opening the data provider's properties.

[image: Data provider properties]

[image: Duplicate rows].

Comment: I added a measure, and I tested it in both IDT and WEBI. By tested I mean I selected the corresponding columns and measures and clicked on show data preview, and got the expected results - output was 10 rows. However, when I clicked on run the query, and when I selected the same columns and moved them into the document, in one column i go the expected values, but in the measures column I got only value '1'.  Why is BO continuing to torture its users with its unintuitiveness?

Comment: Hi Kristof! I'm clueless, why BO returns only value '1' for the measure. Do you know where's the catch?

Comment: Can you update your original question with a screenshot of your data provider, the generated SQL statement and the table you've created in your report where it shows `1`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'data provider' the connection. The screenshot of the report is updated. And the generated query was already in the question.

Comment: Have a look at the *Data* tab (next to *Design*) in Web Intelligence (Java applet) and check the data returned from the database. What is the measure value there?

Comment: ok - in WEBI when I click on Data Provider -> Edit -> Regenerate (using WEBI in other language - German), i get expected result. The measure contains different numbers (not only 1s). That is actually the thing that confuses me - here I see the expected result,but when I click on Run Query, I get only 1s in the measure